Cannot plot 2 surface (3dplot) in one figure in MAPLE
I want to plot sphere z=sqrt(4-x^2-y^2) and cone z=sqrt(x^2+y^2) in one figure in MAPLE.
I only can plot one plot in one figure only.
plot3d(sqrt(-x^2-y^2+4), x = -2 .. 2, y = -2 .. 2)

How to plot two surfaces (3dplot) in one figure in MAPLE?

You can use the plots:-display command to put multiple plots together.
For example,
plots:-display(
  plot3d(sqrt(4-x^2-y^2),
         x=-sqrt(4-y^2)..sqrt(4-y^2),y=-2..2,
         color=red),
  plot3d(sqrt(x^2+y^2),
         x=-2..2,y=-2..2,
         color=blue)
);


